# Java large String returned from findWithinHorizon converted to InputStream

Tags: java, memory-management, inputstream, java.util.scanner

I have wrote an application which in one of its modules parses huge file and saves this file chunk by chunk into a database.

First of all the following code works, and my main problem is to reduce memory usage and general increase in performance.

The following code snippet is a small part of the big picture, but is the most problematic after doing some YourKit profiling, The lines that are marked by */*Here*/* allocate huge amount of memory.

```
....
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file,"UTF-8");
String scannedFarm;
try{

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:^.++$(?:\\r?+\\n)?+){2,100000}+",Pattern.MULTILINE);
    String [] tableName = null;

/*HERE*/while((scannedFarm = fileScanner.findWithinHorizon(p, 0)) != null){
         boolean continuePrevStream = false;
         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(scannedFarm);

         String[] tmpTableName  = scanner.nextLine().split(getSeparator());
         if (tmpTableName.length==2){
             tableName = tmpTableName;
         }else{
             if (tableName==null){
                 continue;
             }
             continuePrevStream = true;
         }
         scanner.close();

/*HERE*/ InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(scannedFarm.getBytes("UTF-8"));
....
```

It is acceptable to allocate huge amount of memory since the String is large (i need it too be such large chunk), My main problem is that the same allocation happens twice as a result of getBytes,

1. So my question is their a way to transfer the *findWithinHorizon* Result directly to *InputStream* without allocating memory twice?
2. Is their more efficient way to achieve the same functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same approach but instead of `findWithinHorizon`, you could try reading each line and searching for the pattern within the line context.  This is sure to reduce memory pressure as you're not buffering the whole file as the API states:

> If horizon is 0, then the horizon is ignored and this method continues
>   to search through the input looking for the specified pattern without
>   bound. **In this case it may buffer all of the input searching for the
>   pattern**.

Something like:

```
while(String line = fileScanner.nextLine() != null) { 
   if(grep for pattern in line) { 

   }
}
```

Comment: buffering the input without bound and backoff is the intention, processing line by line is much slower and unnecessary because all the lines need to be sent to database as single chunk and no processing between the lines is needed, this input-stream is sent as a one chunk into LOAD DATA statement, smaller chunks will cause LOAD DATA to be not effective (as i mentioned , large chunk is intentional)

Comment: I see.  I don't really see anyway around this then.  Did you profile the line by line approach?  How big does your heap get when you buffer the whole file?

Comment: Heap consumption is around 1 GB, line processing has un acceptable time performance.